# Interoperability between Boost and C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

What is the extent of interoperability between C++11 and a recent version of Boost (say 1.55) built with a C++11 compiler.

1. Does the behavior of any library feature change depending on whether I built the libraries with c++11 flags enabled or not?
2. How do language features like lambda functions cooperate with Boost's lambdas?

Comment: Lambda functions and Boost's lambdas don't interfere at all. They are both just function objects. Only C++11 lambdas are compiler generated, and Boost uses expression templates.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119902/23715

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You cannot use objects built with `gcc` with and without `-std=c++11` together. You will get link errors or even runtime crashes. I cannot vouch for other C++ implementations. So at least with `gcc`, you do need to build a separate version of Boost with c++11 mode enabled.
2. They are pretty much independent. They don't cooperate and don't interfere with each other.

**EDIT** I see people are still reading (and upvoting!) this answer. Point 1 is **no longer true** (or perhaps never was true). Versions of gcc from I think 5.1 upwards use an ABI compatible with `-std=<anything>` by default.

Answer (score 2):

No behaviours change: at the code level Boost is compatible with both C++03 and C++11.

However, at the object level you won't be able to mix and match: if your program is compiled as C++11, and you're using some non-header Boost libraries, you will have to build those Boost libraries as C++11 as well. This is because the respective C++ runtimes of your toolchain for each version of the language cannot be guaranteed to have ABI compatibility.