# Can I link an object compiled with clang c++11 with another compiled with c++17

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, c++17, clang++

I'm looking specifically for a clang answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746878/is-it-safe-to-link-c17-c14-and-c11-objects). If I compile one object with `-std=c++11` and another with `-std=c++17` can they be safely linked?

Comment: If both objects are compiled with the same version of the same compiler then maybe.

Comment: Might need a 17 wrapper for the 11 objects.

Comment: But if your compiler supports C++17 then why would you use C++11

Comment: You should be good if you don't try to include a 17 header in a 11 file

Comment: Good question I would think it would work as the C++11 is forwards compatible

Comment: If it works in GCC then there's a good chance that it'll work in Clang too

Comment: Same library linked against?  Any restriction on what the C++11 code uses?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont are you asking if the two objects are linked against different standard libraries? (sorry I got pulled away like immediately after posting)

Comment: @Kerndog73 big project, libraries configured with c++11 and I want to write an executable using some of those libraries for c++17

Comment: @RyanHaining Yes.  There is a linux standard library that differs on the ABI of `std::string` based on which version if I remember rightly (technically between C++03 and C++11, but your C++11 code might use the C++03 ABI).  You can search for "ABI changes" to find if there are more cases like this and check if it applies to your case.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont only one stdlib here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49119902/3081037) by Jonathan Wakely is correct for Clang as well.

**Easy answer**: if you're compiling both of the objects yourself, the `-std` option you choose won't affect the final outcome.

Most of a given C++ ABI is decided by the standard library. The rest is assorted runtime support such as exceptions, compiler builtins (which may actually dispatch to the standard library),  and things like that. `libstdc++` ABI compatibility is an explicit goal of for Clang, so you're ok here.

If you're using the same compiler version, the `-std` option will change which symbols get exposed to code when you compile. However, libstdc++'s ABI for stable features is forwards compatible, so you'd also be OK here too.

**Harder answer**: Your comments suggest you have the source, but if you only have object files and are just doing the final link, there's a good chance it will work unless the version of Clang used to build the `std=c++11` object is very old. The `g++` and `libstdc++` authors went out of their way to version symbols, so the chances of you having something that links, but then fails in a hard to diagnose way is basically zero. (This is referred to in the second to last paragraph in Jonathan's answer).

Again, since Clang aims to keep compatibility with `libstdc++`'s ABI, you should be fine. There are other details, but the vast majority are addressed in Jonathan's answer, and he's in a better position to explain it than I am.