# Linking to C++ static library on linux throws linker errors while building an execuatble

Tags: c++, linux, static, g++, linker-errors

I have a static library `test1.a` built on linux. When I am trying to link against it, the linker throws **undefined reference errors**:

> CMakeFiles/Testserver.dir/src/audio/TestEncoderFactory.cpp.o: In
> function `TestEncoderFactory::GetSupportedEncoders()`:
> TestH264BypassedEncoder.cpp:(.text._ZN10H264BypassedEncoderC2ERKN7cricket10VideoCodecERNS_14TestClientE+0x191):
> `undefined reference to absl::EqualsIgnoreCase(std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >, std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >)`

> TestEncoderFactory.cpp:(.text._ZN10TestEncoderFactory20GetSupportedEncodersEv+0x20b):
> undefined reference to
> `test::SdpAudioFormat::SdpAudioFormat(std::basic_string_view<char,
> std::char_traits >, int, unsigned long,
> std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits,
> std::allocator >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits, std::allocator >,
> std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits,
> std::allocator > >,
> std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits, std::allocator > const,
> std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits,
> std::allocator > > > >&&)'

But then I created a sample program using the same line of code leading to linker errors as shown below and when I build it by linking against the same `test.a` the executable is building perfectly fine:

```
#include <string>
#include <rtc_base/logging.h>
#include <rtc_base/checks.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <absl/strings/match.h>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

int main() {

cout << "testing\n";

RTC_CHECK(absl::EqualsIgnoreCase("", ""));

//RTC_LOG(INFO) << "Testing libwebrtc linking";

bool res = absl::EqualsIgnoreCase("ab", "");
cout << res;

cout << "\nending";

}
```

I built above using `g++ -I./include -I./include/third_party/abseil-cpp  test.cpp -L./lib -ltest1 -o final_ex`
the executable `final_ex` builds successfully.

The other program is a bigger one(and is private and thus can't share) and trying to link against `test1.a` and other are `.so` as mentioned in the command below:

> `/usr/bin/g++ -pthread -g -rdynamic CMakeFiles/testServer.dir/src/Main.cpp.o testxyz.cpp.o -o bin/testServer  -L<lib_loc> -Wl,-rpath,<path....> -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -ltest1 -lprotobuf  -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -ljson-glib-1.0 -lffmpeg -lX11 -ldl`

I also checked many different questions on Stackoverflow but couldn't fix the issue.
Can linking against static and dynamic libs be the cause behind the issue?

**Fix**

*As question is closed so adding the fix details in question itself.*

One important detail I forgot to mention was I used `cxx_std_17` to build my code. Also I was not aware that the static lib test1.a was built using `cxx_std_14`. Once I got to know this I used `cxx_std_14` and all the linker errors were resolved.

I didn't think about it earlier as I was of the understanding that it's safe to link `C++17` and `C++14` as mentioned in answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46746878/6407858) stackoverflow question. But found the hard way that it may not be the case.

Comment: So where is the `cmake` file where this issue is happening?

Comment: @Waqar I was using CMake earlier but now using the g++ command directly. Edited the question also.

Comment: move the `-L<lib_loc> ....` before `-o bin/....`

Comment: @Waqar I tried as you suggested but still getting the linker errors

Comment: `-pthread` should be `-lpthread` and why put that in the start but the rest in the end?

Comment: I was just trying different things mentioned in other SO posts. So just posted the final command I am using. But I have tried using -lpthread also as you mentioned but none helped.

Comment: @Waqar no, -pthread should absolutely not  be -lpthread, never ever.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. can you share why?

Comment: You need to link to abseil libraries. The fact that your little test program can get away with  it means absolutely nothing.

Comment: @Waqar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23250863/difference-between-pthread-and-lpthread-while-compiling

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. the static test1.a has been built with abseil libraries. I can see the abseil-cpp .o files and corresponding symbols when I do `nm test1.a`.
Also that's the reason I am able to use `absl::EqualsIgnoreCase("ab", "");` in my test program also which is then linked against `test1.a`.

Comment: @Waqar `man gcc` says "-pthread \[...] You should use this option consistently for both compilation and linking".  That's a good enough reason for me.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Great! thanks. Never realized this until now.

Comment: What source file or library has the undefined reference?

Comment: The errors are in the executable `testServer` which I am trying to build by linking against `test1.a` and other `*.so`

Comment: Please post the *entire* compiler message. A compiler message never starts with "undefined reference". There should be something before these words, namely the source or object file name and the library name.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I have updated the error message.

Comment: You need to move `-ltest1` down the link line and place it after all libraries that might need it. In addition, `nm` your libraries. If you see a reference to __cxx11, then you are a victim of the dual libstdc++ ABI fiasco and you probably need to upgrade your system or downgrade your compiler.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. the libtest1.a is not required by any library mentioned after it. So moving it down the line didn't help. One thing was that If I move it after -ldl I get the error:
`libtest1.a(latebindingsymboltable_linux.o): undefined reference to symbol 'dlclose@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
/home/yugander/SpiderPorkClientWebCommon/src/SpiderPorkClientWebCommon/server/lib/pipewire/lib/libdl.so: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line`

Comment: Also there are other linker errors which I didn't posted which have reference to `__cxx11`:
::SdpAudioFormat(std::basic_string_view<char, std::char_traits<char> >, int, unsigned long, std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,.

Comment: Does this also indicate issue of dual libstdc++ ABI u mentioned?

Comment: OK so this is not a link order issue but a dual ABI issue. I fixed the dupe.  Basically some but not all of your code is compiled with `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` (or by an ancient gcc). Don't do that.

Comment: if you think that the duplicates don't answer your question, tell me and I'll reopen

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. I did try with -D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0 to fix the ABI issue as mentioned in the tagged question. But the issue remained.  Lateron I figured out that failure was because of `cxx_std_17` and once I changed it to `cxx_std_14` all linker errors were resolved. I never knew that cxx_std_17 and 14 are incompatible.