# Unexpected symbols resolution when linking against c++ library

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

Using `GCC 11`,

```
gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 11.3.0
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

I'm building a library `libsimplemath.a`, based on two objects (`add.o` and `sub.o`), `sub.o` has an external dependency on `undef_symb`:

```
// add.cpp
int add(int a, int b) { return a + b; }

// sub.cpp
#include <string>
void undef_symb(void);
int sub(int a, int b)
{
  std::string s;
  undef_symb();
  return a - b;
}
```

```
g++ -O0 -std=c++20 -o sub.o -c sub.cpp
g++ -O0 -std=c++20 -o add.o -c add.cpp
ar rc libsimplemath.a add.o sub.o
```

Let's say one of the `libsimplemath.a` user has a main only depending on `add` interface:

```
// main.cpp
#include <string>
int add(int, int);
int main()
{
  std::string s = "Hello";
  return add(0, 0);
}
```

When the code is compiled using c++20 flag, everything works fine:

```
g++ -O0 -std=c++20 -o main.o -c main.cpp
g++ -o main main.o -L. -lsimplemath
```

No problem.

However when the code is compiled using c++17 flag (and this is the current user flow), it fails at link time:

```
g++ -O0 -std=c++17 -o main.o -c main.cpp
g++ -o main main.o -L. -lsimplemath                       
/arm/tools/gnu/binutils/2.32/rhe7-x86_64/bin/ld: ./libsimplemath.a(sub.o): in function `sub(int, int)':
sub.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `undef_symb()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here's a [CMake project @ compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/KMMTa4cqz) that reproduces the problem.

For some reasons `sub.o` is also brought by linker and, as it contains an undefined symbol, linking is failing.

To know why `sub.o` is taken into account linker map file can be looked at (`-Wl,-Map=main.map` linker option):

```
Archive member included to satisfy reference by file (symbol)

./libsimplemath.a(add.o)      main.o (add(int, int))
./libsimplemath.a(sub.o)      main.o (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string())
```

`basic_string` stl symbol is resolved in `sub.o`.

By looking at `nm` output we can see that `basic_string` constructor is not defined in `main.o`:

```
nm -aC main.o | grep basic_string
                 U std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()
```

It is defined in `sub.o`:

```
nm -aC sub.o | grep basic_string\(
0000000000000000 W std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()
```

It explains why `sub.o` is brought by linker, and the fail.

The fact that `basic_string` symbols are defined or not in the object file depends on the `-std=c++XX` flag used. Compiling `main.cpp` with `-std=c++20`:

```
 nm -aC main.o | grep basic_string\(
0000000000000000 W std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string()
```

The symbol is defined, no need to resolve it elsewhere, thus `sub.o` is not brought and linking works.

The reason why `basic_string` is defined or not seems to come from the fact that it's defined as extern or not:
in `include/c++/11.3.0/bits/basic_string.tcc`

```
  // Inhibit implicit instantiations for required instantiations,                                                                                                                                          
  // which are defined via explicit instantiations elsewhere.                                                                                                                                              
#if _GLIBCXX_EXTERN_TEMPLATE
  // The explicit instantiation definitions in src/c++11/string-inst.cc and                                                                                                                                
  // src/c++17/string-inst.cc only instantiate the members required for C++17                                                                                                                              
  // and earlier standards (so not C++20's starts_with and ends_with).                                                                                                                                     
  // Suppress the explicit instantiation declarations for C++20, so C++20                                                                                                                                  
  // code will implicitly instantiate std::string and std::wstring as needed.                                                                                                                              
# if __cplusplus <= 201703L && _GLIBCXX_EXTERN_TEMPLATE > 0
  extern template class basic_string<char>;
```

For `std=c++17` the template is `extern` and thus `basic_string` is not defined in `main.o`.

So this use-case seems to break the interoperability between different standard (here `c++17` and `c++20`). Is it expected?

If there is no problem here then it means every single dependency *must* be provided at link time? Even the ones the user (main writer) doesn't care of?
(I didn't find resources claiming it)

Comment: I tried what you proposed, it didn't make it work.
As you noticed it is not failing on more recent gcc (I tested on gcc 9.3.0). From my experiments it is reprocucable on gcc 7.3.0 and gcc 8.3.0

Comment: I updated the case with gcc11, outdating the above comments

Comment: Hi @TedLyngmo, thanks for having a look, the issue comes when you are compiling the static lib with -std=c++20 and main.cpp with -std=c++17. Did you do that? I might be wrong but it looks like you are compiling everything with -std=c++17 in your case.

Comment: Aha, I missed that important detail. I updated the CMake project so it reproduces your problem and put that in your question.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: Romain: You're welcome. @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. It feels like ABI breakage. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746878/is-it-safe-to-link-c17-c14-and-c11-objects), it _should_ work - if this kind if linking isn't in fact IFNDR.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It is still entirely safe to link together C++11, C++15 and C++17 objects. The problem is that the linker stumbles upon a wrong object to link. If you pass main.o and add.o to the linker (instead of libsimplemath) it works. If you add sub.o it stops working (IFNDR but the implementations usually do give a diagnostic). Should the linker bring in sub.o automatically? The standard doesn't attempt to answer this question. It's a QoA issue.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. You're right. I made the `add` function return a `std::string` instead and received that in `main`. Even if compiled with different standards it looks like it [works fine](https://godbolt.org/z/j8e58bqYo).

Answer (score 0):

`extern template class ...` is a totally normal C++ declaration that can appear in user code, regardless of the C++ standard chosen. You are not supposed to instantiate things from the standard library yourself (whether it's legal or not), but the same exact thing happens with any user-defined class template. You can build a virtually identical example using no standard library and no `-std=` options. Just make a template, add `extern template class ...` in one file, and don't add it to another file.

No standard and no ABI can protect you from things like that. You always need to be careful about which objects you link into your program.

Of course it is still a problem in practice and IMHO a bug in the libstdc++ (it should not make easy things hard), but once you know what's going on, there is a simple workaround.

Compile (with `-std=c++20 -O0`) an object that contains this:

```
// for the benefit of C++17 users
// who compile their libraries with -O0
#include <string>
std::string a;
```

and link it to your program before the linker gets a chance to see `sub.o`. For example, put it first in `libsimplemath.a`.

You still can interoperate between C++17 and C++20 just fine. No need to provide every dependency at link time (it would be a horrible thing to do).