# Can we mix c++ standard compile with MSVC?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I think gcc is try to support [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746878/is-it-safe-to-link-c17-c14-and-c11-objects).

But, I can't find any referrence for MSVC.

My code base is currently build on c++17. I would like to use the new coroutine feature in c++20 but don't want to migrate all code rightnow. The goal is to build some components with coroutine support.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it would be better to edit and provide your real use case.

Comment: My code base is currently build on c++17. I would like to use the new coroutine feature in c++20 but don't want to migrate all code rightnow. 

The goal is to build some components with coroutine support.

Comment: you may use [edit] to add your comment into original post.

Comment: MSVC is ABI-compatible between 2015, 2017, and 2019. There were no ABI changes between these versions.  Therefore, I don't see why wouldn't be able to do that. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160

Answer (score 1):

The rules of [MSVC binary compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-160) apply. Objects are link-compatible (as long as you don't use link-time code generation or whole-program optimization) between versions. Since that page doesn't say that any other compiler switches beside `/LTCG` and `/GL` break this promise, `/std:` won't do that either.